# string_length error when pressing backspace and string is less than 0 c++

Tags: c++, string

When I backspace and the string is less than 0 then the application shows the following error

[image: screenshot]

The code I am using is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string a = "";

    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        c = _getch();

        if (c == '\r')
            break;

        if (c == 8)
        {
            cout << '\b';
            cout << ' ';
            cout << '\b';

            a.resize(a.length() - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "*";
            a += c;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please advice?

**EDIT**

I have changed my code to be the following but now when I press backspace it doesn't allow any input into the program.

```
if (!a.empty())
{
    if (c == 8)
    {
        cout << '\b';
        cout << ' ';
        cout << '\b';

        a.resize(a.length() - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "*";
        a += c;
    }
}
else
{
    continue;   
}
```

Comment: Note that it's a [`std::length_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error) (a thrown exception), not a string_length error, and "string less than 0" doesn't have a clear meaning.

Comment: why are you replacing a backspace hit with spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't resize below zero... this seems pretty straightforward.  Edit - that is to say, check if the string is empty before reducing the size.

Comment: How would go about doing this as I am pretty lost with it.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question could you please advise?

Comment: You've got the if in the wrong place.  In your current version if the string ever hits 0 length you will never be able to add characters back onto it.  You only need to prevent it from going below zero length.  Think about the logic before you write the code.